# How to rerender calendar component on event data change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am using react-big-calendar and getting event data from props (redux connect) from an API . How do I trigger a rerender when the data updates (add/delete or changed) and avoid infinite useEffect loop?

My code:

```
export const SelectableCalendar = (props: CalendarProps) => {
  const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
  const bookedEvents = props.events.bookings;

  const eventList = bookedEvents.map((event: CalendarProps) => {
    return {
      start: moment(event.time.startTime),
      end: moment(event.time.endTime),
      title: event.title,
    };
  });

  const [events, setEvents] = useState(
    eventList as CalendarEvent[] 
  );
```

What do I put in the [?] to rerender when new events are added/removed or changed?

```
useEffect(()=>{setEvents(eventList as CalendarEvent[])},[?])
```

The calendar component is as such:

```
      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={events}
        defaultView="month"
        defaultDate={new Date(year, month, day)}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        titleAccessor="title"
      />
```

Comment: Where does "data updates (add/delete or changed)" occur? Via props passed to `SelectableCalendar` and rendered into `Calendar`? Are you duplicating app state into local component state?

Comment: Yes via props passed to SelectableCalendar and rendered into Calendar.

Comment: Looks like you are saving `eventsList` into state, and `eventsList` is mapped from `bookedEvents ` which is `props.events.bookings`, so the dependency is likely `props.events.bookings`.

Comment: When I do   `useEffect(() => {
    setEvents(eventList as CalendarEvent[]);
  }, [props.events.bookings]);` I get "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'eventList'"

Comment: You can move all the logic into the effect if you don't need it anywhere else in the component. `EventList` is redeclared every render so if you used that as a dependency it would cause an infinite loop. If you need it to be declared *outside* the effect then use `useMemo` to memoize it's value and use that in the effect.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the problem! I didn't realize eventList was being redeclared every render causing infinite loop.